ElasticSearch 7.10 - fetch large amount of sorted docs in parallel, like Oracle DB DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task
I am experimenting how to do PIT search + search_after in ElasticSearch 7.10.2.
I am fetching 30 millions lines from ES and each page is 100K. It takes about 1.5 min to fetch one page(through VPN, if in remote machine it's about 30s). This is too slow and I want to parallel execute it.
The reason is that the objective is to compare the data from Oracle DB with data from ElasticSearch, and on Oracle DB side, thanks to DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task and DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL, I can retrieve ~30 millions rows under 1 min with parallel level of 20. I wonder if ES has similar kind of native support for fetching large amount of data in parallel by chunking in advance.
The problem is, search_after seems to deem an order and before knowing the next sort, you cannot start another chunk. Is there any way to get around this? Thanks.
In Oracle, I chunk table by ID column, which is NUMBER and indexed. (SEE this question and my answer). In ES I don't have ID, but instead I have FIELD1 which is also _id, and I need to sort by _id. The reason why I don't sort on FIELD1 is because I cannot, it's not keyword and I cannot change definition of this index.
FIELD1 is a string, but only consists 15 digits of numbers.
My ES query looks like:
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "companyId": {
        "value": "40*"
      }
    }
  },
  "fields":[
        "FIELD1", "FIELD2"
  ],
  "sort": {"_id": "asc"},
  "size": 100000,
  "_source": false,
  "pit": {
        "id": "<a very long id>",
        "keep_alive": "1m"
  },
  "track_total_hits": false
}

and 2..n query will add search_after: ["<last hit value of FIELD1 from previous page>"]
EDIT:
Also, I find out that I cannot get max and min aggregation on _id(as it's a String)/FIELD1(is not a keyword), even that I think it could be ordered like numbers. So I cannot do range chunking search on _id, as I don't know where to start/stop.

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scan-scroll.html
#1 Divide the Data Set
Manually partition your data based on (like _id ranges)
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 10000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "_id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

#2 Implement Parallel Scrolling/ search after
Run multiple scroll queries in parallel in code.
First partition (e.g., IDs 0 to 99999)
(Increase time as needed)
POST /this_index/_search?scroll=5m
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "_id": {
        "gte": "0",
        "lt": "1000000"
      }
    }
  }
}

Get batch for the first set
POST /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll": "5m", 
  "scroll_id": "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAA..."
}

Repeat this for every partition's scroll_id until no hits in response.

But isn't scroll API not recommended now? That's why I never read that part of documentation. We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time (PIT).

It is good that I could partition the index, but does Scroll API always use the same scroll_id? Because in PIT, pit_id could change, that's why I cannot parallel execute them. Every response will contain the PIT id used, next search needs it, and it could be updated without any notification.

I will try partition first, and using the range of _id in query; let's see if it is faster. Then I don't have to specify page size.

@WesternGun - True . You can use start scroll method  instead of scan and scroll.

Sorry that I couldn't accept the answer, I realize that while slice is doable for a PIT in current version (8), I am using 7.10 and can only slice in a context of scroll. And due to that doc does not recommend scroll api anymore and it says If you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time (PIT), then I think I can only use PIT and have no way to parallel run it
